# Keras / NN - Applying different scaling/normalization on inputs

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, normalization

on my journey learning ML I was testing some NN and I was seeing that my output doesn't seem to take into consideration one of my 3 inputs which is very important.

My dataset is composed of 4 cols (csv):

- 3 are numbers (including the output) between 1 000 and can go up to 150 000 000
- 1 is a number between 0 and 100 which is the one that's not taken in consideration by my NN

I scale my dataset this way using MinMaxScaler from scikit-learn:

```
df = pd.read_csv('rawData.csv')
dataset = df.values

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
dataset = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

X = dataset[:,0:3] # input
Y = dataset[:,3]   # output
```

I also use another way to scale my data (when I want to test my model):

```
min_test = np.min(runset)
max_test = np.max(runset)

normalized = (runset - min_test) / (max_test - min_test)

test = model.predict(normalized)

result = test * (max_test - min_test) + min_test
```

So my question is: **Is it possible and recommended to use different scales for different inputs?** If yes how do I do that?

Comment: What does `Y` represent?

Comment: @sentence Y represents the 3rd col of my csv file wich is my output (large numbers as i said in my post)

Comment: Then, why do you scale the ouput? Is there any reason?

Comment: No, you're right i shouldn't scale the output, didn't even noticed i changed it. But at first I was not scaling Y and the problem was already there.

Comment: @Halt You should also scale your output as well because your output is in range of 1 000 to 150 000 000. This is vary large value to manipulate by gradient so, it might change from 1 000 to 100 000 on next iteration which can change gradient at very high ups and downs and also there might be vast difference in your loss as well. To avoid this I would prefer to use normalization on outlut as well with mean and standard deviation so, model can easily converge. And when you predict the result use the same mean and standard deviation values (which you have used for normalize) to retrive the data.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is another question: do I have **prior knowledge** about the importance of the features characterizing my dataset?

- if yes, I **may** scale my data in such a way that more important features have larger variance/range.
- if not, I **should** scale my data in such a way that features have mean 0 and standard deviation 1. Why? Mainly for improving numerical condition, removing the problem of scale dependence of the initial weights, making the training process faster, and reducing the risk of getting stuck in local optima.

Do not underestimate the sensitivity of gradient descent methods to scaling.

Finally, remember to use statistics (mean and standard deviation) from the training set to standardize the validation/test set.